# Calculate previous month in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

i am having problems to get the previous month quantity

I have a table with this shape:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM UNNEST ([
    STRUCT('Europe' AS continent, 'Germany' AS country, 'Company A' AS company, DATE('2023-01-31') AS date, 120 AS sales),
    ('Europe', 'Germany', 'Company A', '2022-12-31', 198),
    ('Europe', 'Germany', 'Company A', '2022-11-30', 167),
    ('Europe', 'Germany', 'Company A', '2022-10-31', 8),
    ('Europe', 'Italy', 'Company A', '2022-12-31', 155),
    ('Europe', 'Italy', 'Company A', '2022-11-30', 93),
    ('Europe', 'Italy', 'Company A', '2022-10-31', 95),
    ('Asia', 'China', 'Company A', '2023-01-31', 128),
    ('Asia', 'China', 'Company A', '2022-12-31', 177),
    ('Asia', 'China', 'Company A', '2022-11-30', 153),
    ('Asia', 'China', 'Company A', '2022-10-31', 3),
    ('America', 'USA', 'Company A', '2023-01-31', 15),
    ('America', 'USA', 'Company A', '2022-12-31', 59),
    ('America', 'USA', 'Company A', '2022-11-30', 116),
    ('America', 'USA', 'Company A', '2022-10-31', 122),
    ('Europe', 'Germany', 'Company B', '2023-01-31', 70),
    ('Europe', 'Germany', 'Company B', '2022-12-31', 94),
    ('Europe', 'Germany', 'Company B', '2022-11-30', 24),
    ('Europe', 'Germany', 'Company B', '2022-10-31', 143),
    ('Europe', 'Italy', 'Company B', '2023-01-31', 0),
    ('Europe', 'Italy', 'Company B', '2022-12-31', 11),
    ('Europe', 'Italy', 'Company B', '2022-11-30', 189),
    ('Europe', 'Italy', 'Company B', '2022-10-31', 131),
    ('Asia', 'China', 'Company B', '2023-01-31', 157),
    ('Asia', 'China', 'Company B', '2022-12-31', 34),
    ('Asia', 'China', 'Company B', '2022-11-30', 112),
    ('Asia', 'China', 'Company B', '2022-10-31', 97),
    ('America', 'USA', 'Company B', '2023-01-31', 146),
    ('America', 'USA', 'Company B', '2022-12-31', 41),
    ('America', 'USA', 'Company B', '2022-11-30', 83),
    ('America', 'USA', 'Company B', '2022-10-31', 127)
  ]))
```

and I am trying to get the sales of the previous month for each continent, country and company.

If you can see, the Company A in Italy doesnt have sales in '2023-01-31' and this is causing a trouble

I have got this:

```
SELECT continent, country, company, date, SUM(sales),
  (SELECT SUM(sales)
  FROM data
  WHERE date = LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(d.date, INTERVAL -1 MONTH),MONTH)
  AND continent = d.continent
  AND country = d.country
  AND company = d.company) AS sales_previous_month
FROM data d
GROUP BY continent, country, company, date
ORDER BY continent, country, company, date DESC
```

and with this SQL i can get the previous month sales without problems, but the problem come when i try to aggregate by date. If i export this to a CSV and sum the columns group by date, i have this totals:

```
|    date    |  sales  | sales_previous_month |
| 2023-01-31 |   636   |        614           |
| 2022-12-31 |   769   |        937           |
| 2022-11-30 |   937   |        726           |
| 2022-10-31 |   726   |         0            |
```

I wish get that my january sales_previous_month sum the sales for Italy, Company A of december too, some suggestions?

Thanks in advance, regards

Answer (score 1):

Since your data is pretty well formatted by month already, you can actually use [LAG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#lag) here. If you want 0s instead of nulls, you can use [COALESCE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#coalesce) as well.

Here's what I think you're looking for:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM UNNEST ([
    STRUCT('Europe' AS continent, 'Germany' AS country, 'Company A' AS company, DATE('2023-01-31') AS date, 120 AS sales),
    ('Europe', 'Germany', 'Company A', '2022-12-31', 198),
    ('Europe', 'Germany', 'Company A', '2022-11-30', 167),
    ('Europe', 'Germany', 'Company A', '2022-10-31', 8),
    ('Europe', 'Italy', 'Company A', '2022-12-31', 155),
    ('Europe', 'Italy', 'Company A', '2022-11-30', 93),
    ('Europe', 'Italy', 'Company A', '2022-10-31', 95),
    ('Asia', 'China', 'Company A', '2023-01-31', 128),
    ('Asia', 'China', 'Company A', '2022-12-31', 177),
    ('Asia', 'China', 'Company A', '2022-11-30', 153),
    ('Asia', 'China', 'Company A', '2022-10-31', 3),
    ('America', 'USA', 'Company A', '2023-01-31', 15),
    ('America', 'USA', 'Company A', '2022-12-31', 59),
    ('America', 'USA', 'Company A', '2022-11-30', 116),
    ('America', 'USA', 'Company A', '2022-10-31', 122),
    ('Europe', 'Germany', 'Company B', '2023-01-31', 70),
    ('Europe', 'Germany', 'Company B', '2022-12-31', 94),
    ('Europe', 'Germany', 'Company B', '2022-11-30', 24),
    ('Europe', 'Germany', 'Company B', '2022-10-31', 143),
    ('Europe', 'Italy', 'Company B', '2023-01-31', 0),
    ('Europe', 'Italy', 'Company B', '2022-12-31', 11),
    ('Europe', 'Italy', 'Company B', '2022-11-30', 189),
    ('Europe', 'Italy', 'Company B', '2022-10-31', 131),
    ('Asia', 'China', 'Company B', '2023-01-31', 157),
    ('Asia', 'China', 'Company B', '2022-12-31', 34),
    ('Asia', 'China', 'Company B', '2022-11-30', 112),
    ('Asia', 'China', 'Company B', '2022-10-31', 97),
    ('America', 'USA', 'Company B', '2023-01-31', 146),
    ('America', 'USA', 'Company B', '2022-12-31', 41),
    ('America', 'USA', 'Company B', '2022-11-30', 83),
    ('America', 'USA', 'Company B', '2022-10-31', 127)
  ]))
select *, coalesce(lag(sales) over(partition by continent, country, company order by date),0) as previous_month 
from data
```

Note how we use the partition to pick what separates distinct groups.

Answer (score 0):

Using a window function as Mike showed in the answer is getter solution than the inner select.

You want to have a row included if this or previous month was a sale. Therfore a `union` can be used.

```sql
WITH data AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM UNNEST ([
    STRUCT('Europe' AS continent, 'Germany' AS country, 'Company A' AS company, DATE('2023-01-31') AS date, 120 AS sales),
    ('Europe', 'Germany', 'Company A', '2022-12-31', 198),

   # please insert all other rows again

    ('America', 'USA', 'Company B', '2022-10-31', 127)
  ])),

  tbl as (
    Select * except(date, sales), # current month
      date,
      sales, 0 as sales_previous_month  
      from data
    union all # combine
    select * except(date, sales), # last month
      LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL -1 MONTH),MONTH),
      0,sales #last ,month
      from data )


SELECT continent, country, company, date, 
  SUM(sales) as sales,
  sum(sales_previous_month) as sales_previous_month
FROM tbl
GROUP BY continent, country, company, date
ORDER BY continent, country, company, date DESC
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! Yeah i tried the window function before write the post, but the problem with that was that if i have a gap in some month would give me an incorrect amount, but your solution is perfect!